# Http POST works on std Java does not work correctly on Android

Tags: java, android, http

I am banging my head over the following code that works on std java from the command line but does not work in Android on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.2. I'm including two variations of my attempting to perform a post to http://cleverbot.com/webservicemin. The original post logic was taken from the [chatterbot API](http://code.google.com/p/chatter-bot-api/) where the revised logic was my attempt to use different Http APIs available in Java. This is a naive attempt at including the [chatterbot API](http://code.google.com/p/chatter-bot-api/) in a test project. The original works from a Main app on the cmd line using standard Java while neither version will work in Android.

```
private static String revisedPostLogic(String url, Map<String, String> parameters) throws IOException {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(parameters.size());
    for(Map.Entry<String,String>eachEntry : parameters.entrySet())
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(eachEntry.getKey(),eachEntry.getValue()));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    ByteArrayOutputStream rawResponse = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(rawResponse);
    return rawResponse.toString();
}

private static String old_post_logic(String url, Map<String, String> parameters) throws Exception {
    URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    ((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    osw.write(parametersToWWWFormURLEncoded(parameters));
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
    Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int n = 0;
    while ((n = r.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        w.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    r.close();
    return w.toString();
}
```

With the revised logic I get a no response from server exception and with the original logic I get an EOFException.

**Update**

I tried running this from Android and desktop Java and I get a discrepancy:

```
new java.net.URL("http://cleverbot.com/webservicemin").openConnection().getResponseCode()
```

On desktop Java I get a response code 200. (I haven't tried reading the stream but I'm guessing it would return the text "DENIED") On Android I get "EOFException". On desktop Java (using Groovy as a shortcut now), I dump the response code, headers and response content and I get:

```
response code: 200
Headers: [null:[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], SC:[6870], RPS:[server52054], MIME-Version:[1.0], Content-Length:[29], Expires:[Mon, 18 Feb 2013 20:07:20 GMT], Set-Cookie:[RPS=server52054, JSESSIONID=6C765C93A085F67D69F800D9EB76646C; Path=/], Connection:[keep-alive], Server:[Jabberwacky], RLM:[2416], Cache-Control:[no-cache;no-store], Pragma:[no-cache], Date:[Mon, 18 Feb 2013 19:56:42 GMT], Content-Type:[text/html;charset=iso-8859-1]]
Response: DENIED
```

Again I cannot get passed the response code if I try the same on Android. I can connect to the root URL without the path without issue, it's just when I attempt to hit the path off of the root url is when I get the EOFException with either a GET or a POST. I've also tried moving the outputstreamwriter close() call toward the end so I can read the response code before closing the output stream. I still get the EOFException in this case. (I've learned from experience that closing the outputstream prematurely in a mobile app can shut down your entire connection.)

Comment: Are you running from the UI(main) thread? It *should* give a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` if that's the case, but just trying to cover the bases.

Comment: no, I am pushing this networking logic off to a bg thread. Everything works except for the POST. If I change the POST to a GET it works. (returns the contents of the HTTP request.) The problem is definitely narrowed to POSTing to that particular path on the web server with the name/value pairs the API provides. I would go as far as to try posting the same req to a local mock web server but I fiugred I'd ask here 1st.

Comment: Why not just use a get then and add a parameter `&method=post`

Comment: @Matt, I'll try that, however I should clarify. A get to the root path on the server is what is working. A GET or POST request to the path in question fails with the above "NoServerResponse" and "EOF" exceptions. I can pull it up in the phone browser and I get an empty page with only the text "DENIED". Again, POSTing from Java using a command line Main app works and the API is merely sending 8 name/value pairs. I'm not sure what the discrepancy is.

Comment: Why don't you just compare both posts from Java and your Galaxy thing and see if you find any differences?

Comment: jdb, that's my next step. One moment...

Comment: I've skipped both using GET with method=POST and comparing the POST requests as I've narrowed my problem to connecting to the "webservicemin" path off of the root URL. For whatever reason I cannot connect to this path from Android. I've updated my post with the response code and headers as seen from desktop java.

Comment: Ok, I just changed from CleverBot to Jaberwacky which only changes the base URL (everything else in the program is exactly the same!) and it works all the way through on both the phone and on the desktop! I am completely befuddled! I now use this to create my bot: new ChatterBotFactory().create(ChatterBotType.JABBERWACKY);} The new URL is http://jabberwacky.com/webservicemin.